# How to take sum of column with same id and different table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 following table structure
first is like this

```
szCustId    szArClassId    decCreditLimit   szPaymentTermId
22101100071    AMORE        0.00            30 HARI_AMORE    
22101100071    BELLISIMO    500.00          17 HARI_BELLISIMO
22101100071    CAPE         0.00            17 HARI_CAPEDISC
22101100071    FOOD         0.00            17 HARI_FOOD
22101100071    GFES         1000.00         0 HARI_GFES
22101100071    GILBEYS      0.00            17 HARI_GILBEYS
22101100071    GZERO        0.00            13 HARI_GZERO
22101100071    AMORE        0.00            30 HARI_AMORE    
22101100069    BELLISIMO    500.00          17 HARI_BELLISIMO
22101100069    CAPE         0.00            17 HARI_CAPEDISC
22101100069    FOOD         0.00            17 HARI_FOOD
22101100888    FOOD         0.00            17 HARI_FOOD
22101100888    GFES         1000.00         0 HARI_GFES
22101100888    GILBEYS      0.00            17 HARI_GILBEYS
22101100888    GZERO        0.00            13 HARI_GZERO
```

and the second table (that i want to update) is this

```
szCustId    bAllowToCredit    decCreditLimit    
22101100071 1                   0.00    
22101100069 1                   0.00    
22101100888 1                   0.00
```

I need to take a sum of `decCreditLimit` of matching or group by particular `szCustId`

so the result (in table 2) would be like this

```
szCustId    bAllowToCredit    decCreditLimit    
22101100071 1                   1500.00 
22101100069 1                   500.00  
22101100888 1                   1000.00
```

How can I write this SQL query?

Comment: Where possible, don't *store* data that can be calculated - a *stored* piece of calculated data can easily become out of date. Do you have a specific reason for wanting to store these `SUM()` in a table, rather than, say, calculating them in a view?

Comment: it is because in my program, those two tables linked in one form, and for beginning balance, the user only update data from one table (by excel template) so instead i have to update in form one by one, i'd rather sum from table 1, and update another table :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `join` two tables and use `sum` aggregate function with the `group by` clause to calculate total `decCreditLimit` for each `szCustId` and `bAllowToCredit`:

```
select t2.szCustId
     , t2.bAllowToCredit
     , sum(t1.decCreditLimit) as decCreditLimit 
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.szCustId = t2.szCustId
group by t2.szCustId
       , t2.bAllowToCredit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select a.szCustId,a.bAllowToCredit,b.decCreditLimit  from tablesecond a
join(
select szCustId,sum(decCreditLimit) as decCreditLimit  from tablefirst)b
on a.szCustId=b.szCustId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE t2 SET t2.decCreditLimit = (SELECT SUM(decCreditLimit) 
                                   FROM Table1 t1
                                   WHERE t1.szCustId = t2.szCustId)
FROM Table2 t2
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple group by will do the task -

```
SELECT t2.szCustId
     , t2.bAllowToCredit
     , sum(t1.decCreditLimit)
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.szCustId = t2.szCustId
GROUP BY t2.szCustId
       , t2.bAllowToCredit
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Calculate column sum from first table and then update on seconde table like this.

`Update t2
Set t2.decCreditLimit = t1.Sum_Column 
From Table2 t2 
(
Select szCustId,Sum(t1.decCreditLimit) as Sum_Column
From Table1 t1
group by t1.szCustId
)A where A.szCustId = t2.szCustId`